# fit image in ellipse in pdflib

Tags: pdflib

I am using the pdflib library to generate the pdf for my online booking system. I'm new with pdflib library. I have tried a lot but not getting how I can set image into the ellipse with pdflib.

I'm using

```
$pdflib->ellipse ( 10 , 30, x_radius, y_radius);
```

It just draws the ellipse. How can I set image inside it ?

Comment: You can't embed an image inside the ellipse directly, but you can use basic trig/geometry to calculate a bounding box whose corners lie on top of the elipse, and use those as the coordinates to embed your image. Or, you could embed an image and define an elliptical mask on it so only an ellipse-shaped part is visible.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply... I have almost 5-8 images per page. And doing in that manner would not be advisable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use clip method provided by PDFLib, like:

```
$pdflib->ellipse ( 10 , 30, x_radius, y_radius);
$pdflib->clip ();
$pdflib->fit_image($image, $x, $y, $options);
```

This will cut the image in the ellipse shape and also that image will fit into that.

Thanks!